# TortoiseGit commit failed due to authentication, why don't modified files show anymore?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGit on Windows 10.

I checked out a project from our company's Git and made a bunch of changes.

In Windows Explorer, I right-clicked on the project folder, and chose TortoiseGit > Check for Modifications.

All my modifications displayed in the list.  I selected all, entered a comment, and clicked "Commit & Push".

It didn't work because of an authentication error (which is an intermittent problem on our company network, sometimes authentication fails for no reason, they are supposedly working on it).

The problem is, the changes did not get committed but now none of the modifications will display in the list when I do a "Check for Modifications" again.

The list is always empty.

I don't understand what state I'm in ... the changes do not appear in the GitLab web view of the project, and the files on my PC do have the changes in place.  But TortoiseGit will not show me the modifications.

Is there a way to tell TortoiseGit to somehow return back to what it knew before the auth failure?

Comment: Do you have access to git (like, git based on terminal)? If so, go to the directory of the project and check `git status`, `git log` and `git reflog`. Add anything relevant from that output to your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pressed a button called "Commit and push"

Even though the button is called "Commit and push", it is translated to the git layer, and in this later, commit and push are distinct actions. This means its possible that either action might fail.

In your case, the commit action succeeded, but the push failed.

To fix it, just press the push button in the gui, or do `git push` from the terminal

Comment: Thanks!  That's it.  A "Push" fixed it.

Comment: How do I see if there's anything that's been "Committed" that is ready to be "Pushed"?

Comment: I actually had to install TortoiseGit to answer that question. There are multiple places in the application where you can see it, but all those places aren't where you usually would look for it: On the "show log" page, it will show that "master" is not at the same place as "origin/master", when there are unpushed commits, and on the "revision graph" you will also see that "origin/master" isn't at the same place as "master" when you have unpushed commits. Can I suggest doing a commit without pushing, and then looking yourself at the places you frequently use, to look for indicators there?